# Multiptiple selections from a database

Tags: php

How do I modify this snippet. Right now it is working good and if $thisorthat = "1" it executes a function for all the ones labelled 1, If I change it to "2" it executes a function for all labelled 2. How do I say 1 AND 2, or 1, 2, and 4, etc. What is the proper format for that?

```
foreach ($values as $v) {
    $thisorthat = $v[$thisorthatKey];
    if ($thisorthat = "1") {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: You could look into a Switch http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Please give us a sample of what `$values` looks like. Also, you mention, "... it executes a function..." but your code doesn't reflect that. Could you update your question with a complete example of what you're trying to do? A complete example might change the approach someone suggests. Thx.

Comment: Oh, and use '==' instead of '=' within your `if` statement.

Comment: Hi Henny, please mark one of the answers as the right answer if you've found one useful. So your question can be closed. If that's not the case, feel free to drop a message.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `switch` *(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)*:

**Example code:**

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case "apple":
        echo "i is apple";
        break;
    case "bar":
        echo "i is bar";
        break;
    case "cake":
        echo "i is cake";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Invalid";
}
?>
```

**Documentation:** http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Next to `switch` you could use `elseif` *(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)*:

**Other solution:**

```
<?php
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}
?>
```

**Documentation:** http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Sadly some do minus my answer without giving any feedback. While this example will do it for you.

Comment: I don't see why this has been down voted. It clearly answers the OP question and gives clear examples along with the documentation links.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extend if statement to anything you need. In this case **or operator** `||` can help. (Do not forget using `double equator` for comparison)

```
foreach ($values as $v) {
    $thisorthat = $v[$thisorthatKey];
    if ($thisorthat == "1" || $thisorthat == "2" || $thisorthat == "4") {
    continue;
    }
}
```

you can also use an array and search if variable exists in array:

```
$numbers = array("1", "2", "4");
foreach ($values as $v) {
   $thisorthat = $v[$thisorthatKey];
   if (in_array($thisorthat, $numbers)){
   continue;
   }
}
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I used if ($NeworUsed = "1" || $NeworUsed = "2") {
            continue; And it work for value 2 but ignored 1

Comment: Have you used double equator?

Comment: `($NeworUsed = "1" || $NeworUsed = "2"` should be: `($NeworUsed == 1 || $NeworUsed == 2)`. Do you see the difference about == and = ?

Comment: Yes. Single `=` is assignment tool and `==` is `comparison` operator.  @RonnieOosting

Comment: Sorry @AliSheikhpour, my comment was ment for OP

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write SQL Query, saying:

SELECT 
          thisorthatKey(being your column) 
  FROM    YourTable 
  WHERE   thisorthatKey IN (1, 2, 4)

and then fetch the data as an array and work with this array?

Comment: That's probably what he is doing with `$values`.

Answer (score 1):

For using logical **AND** (**&&**), you will need two variables, obviously,

```
$thisorthat = "1"; (or) $thisorthat = "2"; (or) so on..
```

If you could hardcode these values beforehand, then you could do so in an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and loop through it in any way you want:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(); // $arr = []; PHP 5.4 and higher
    $arr[] = "1",
    $arr[] = "2",
    $arr[] = "value",
    ...
    ...
?>
```

However if you're working with logical **OR** (**||**), you can either use an [else if ladder](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php), or use a [switch-case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement (as mentioned by Ronnie Oosting) combined with the logical OR operators in the conditions.

```
<?php
    ...
    if ($thisorthat == "1" || $thisorthat == "2") {
    ...
    } elseif ($thisorthat == "1" || $thisorthat == "2" || $thisorthat == "4")  {
   ...
    }
?>
```